# Monotonic clock on OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, posix, clock, timing

CLOCK_MONOTONIC does not seem available, so clock_gettime is out.

I've read in some places that mach_absolute_time() might be the right way to go, but after reading that it was a 'cpu dependent value', it instantly made me wonder if it is using rtdsc underneath.  Thus, the value could drift over time even if it is monotonic.  Also, issues with thread affinity could result in meaningfully different results from calling the function (making it not monotonic across all cores).

Of course, that is just speculation.  Does anyone know how mach_absolute_time actually works?  I'm actually looking for a replacement to clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC... or something like it for OSX.  No matter what the clock source is, I expect at least millisecond precision and millisecond accuracy.

I'd just like to understand what clocks are available, which clocks are monotonic, if certain clocks drift, have thread affinity issues, aren't supported on all Mac hardware, or take a 'super high' number of cpu cycles to execute.

Here are the links I was able to find about this topic (some are already dead links and not findable on archive.org):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1398/_index.html
http://www.wand.net.nz/~smr26/wordpress/2009/01/19/monotonic-time-in-mac-os-x/
http://www.meandmark.com/timing.pdf

Thanks!
Brett

Comment: As far as I can read, `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` doesn't guarantee that the value won't drift or that there aren't issues with thread affinity either.

Comment: A bit over my head, but `mach_absolute_time` does indeed use rtdsc as can be seen from the [source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-320.1.3/i386/mach/mach_absolute_time.c "mach_absolute_time.c").

Comment: @cobbal: thanks for finding that!  That definitely rules mach_absolute_time out for me.  It is intended for quick, short measurements since the value can drift.

Comment: possible duplicate of [clock_gettime alternative in Mac OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167269/clock-gettime-alternative-in-mac-os-x)

Comment: @zneak: that article is specifically for non monotonic timing on OSX.

Comment: @Brett, the second answer describes `clock_get_time`, and the [documentation](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-792.13.8/osfmk/man/clock_get_time.html) for it mentions that they're all monotonic unless tampered with `clock_set_time`.

Comment: @zneak: the lack of a set_time type function is the defining attribute of a monotonic clock.  a monotonic clock can never go backwards even if we pass through daylight savings time between subsequent queries to the clock.  from the clock_gettime man page: "CLOCK_MONOTONIC
Clock that cannot be set and represents monotonic time since some unspecified starting point."

Comment: @Brett, worry not, for `clock_set_time` [systematically returns `KERN_FAILURE`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-792.13.8/osfmk/kern/clock_oldops.c). As of which one would be appropriate, [`SYSTEM_CLOCK` "advances monotonically and uniformly"](http://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-344.2/osfmk/mach/clock_types.h). This sounds a lot like `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`.

Comment: @zneak, would you like to post this as an answer since its the closest thing yet?  also, advice not to call clock_set_time in general: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1486.2.11/osfmk/man/clock_set_time.html

Comment: Just in case it helps you save some time writing code — https://bitbucket.org/yocto/snippets/src/master/

Comment: you can also read the Mach source just to make sure  :) http://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2422.1.72/libsyscall/wrappers/mach_absolute_time.s

Comment: Note that with macOS Sierra (10.12) from late 2016 onward (but not Mac OS X El Capitan, 10.11, or earlier), the o/s provides `clock_gettime()` with `clock_getres()` reporting 1000, meaning that the clock ticks are at about 1 µs, or `tv_nsec` is always a multiple of 1000.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The Mach kernel provides access to system clocks, out of which at least one (`SYSTEM_CLOCK`) is [advertised by the documentation](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2422.1.72/osfmk/mach/clock_types.h) as being monotonically incrementing.

```
#include <mach/clock.h>
#include <mach/mach.h>

clock_serv_t cclock;
mach_timespec_t mts;

host_get_clock_service(mach_host_self(), SYSTEM_CLOCK, &cclock);
clock_get_time(cclock, &mts);
mach_port_deallocate(mach_task_self(), cclock);
```

`mach_timespec_t` has nanosecond precision. I'm not sure about the accuracy, though.

Mac OS X supports three clocks:

- `SYSTEM_CLOCK` returns the time since boot time;
- `CALENDAR_CLOCK` returns the UTC time since 1970-01-01;
- `REALTIME_CLOCK` is deprecated and is the same as `SYSTEM_CLOCK` in its current implementation.

The [documentation for `clock_get_time`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2422.1.72/osfmk/man/clock_get_time.html) says the clocks are monotonically incrementing unless someone calls `clock_set_time`. Calls to `clock_set_time` are [discouraged](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2422.1.72/osfmk/man/clock_set_time.html) as it could break the monotonic property of the clocks, and in fact, [the current implementation returns `KERN_FAILURE`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2422.1.72/osfmk/kern/clock_oldops.c) without doing anything.

Comment: Looks like the `mach_task_self()` no longer exists, There is a `mach_task_self_`.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Which OS is that? El Capitan?

Comment: Sorry, it is Yosemite 10.10.5. And I am doing iOS development. I have latest iOS 9 SDK installed. My deployment target is 8.0

Comment: @zhaow `mach_task_self()` is one of the fundamental functions of Darwin and iOS, tvOS as well as macOS all base on Dawin. Without that function the whole system would stop working as no interaction between user space and kernel space is possible w/o it, so I'm pretty sure that this function still exists and always will exist as long as Apple uses the mach microkernel in Darwin.

Comment: From testing (on macOS Sierra 10.12.2), it appears that the `SYSTEM_CLOCK` supports nanosecond resolution, but `CALENDAR_CLOCK` only supports microsecond resolution; the value of `mts.tv_nsec` is always a multiple of 1000 with `CALENDAR_CLOCK`.  (And `mach_task_self()` exists enough that there was no problem compiling the code shown in the question.)

Comment: @Zhao If you don't have `mach_task_self()`, you're not including the right header file. (It's a macro defined to `mach_task_self_`)

Answer (score 9):

After looking up a few different answers for this I ended up defining a header which emulates clock_gettime on mach:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/_types/_timespec.h>
#include <mach/mach.h>
#include <mach/clock.h>

#ifndef mach_time_h
#define mach_time_h

/* The opengroup spec isn't clear on the mapping from REALTIME to CALENDAR
 being appropriate or not.
 http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/basedefs/time.h.html */

// XXX only supports a single timer
#define TIMER_ABSTIME -1
#define CLOCK_REALTIME CALENDAR_CLOCK
#define CLOCK_MONOTONIC SYSTEM_CLOCK

typedef int clockid_t;

/* the mach kernel uses struct mach_timespec, so struct timespec
    is loaded from <sys/_types/_timespec.h> for compatability */
// struct timespec { time_t tv_sec; long tv_nsec; };

int clock_gettime(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec *tp);

#endif
```

and in mach_gettime.c

```
#include "mach_gettime.h"
#include <mach/mach_time.h>

#define MT_NANO (+1.0E-9)
#define MT_GIGA UINT64_C(1000000000)

// TODO create a list of timers,
static double mt_timebase = 0.0;
static uint64_t mt_timestart = 0;

// TODO be more careful in a multithreaded environement
int clock_gettime(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec *tp)
{
    kern_return_t retval = KERN_SUCCESS;
    if( clk_id == TIMER_ABSTIME)
    {
        if (!mt_timestart) { // only one timer, initilized on the first call to the TIMER
            mach_timebase_info_data_t tb = { 0 };
            mach_timebase_info(&tb);
            mt_timebase = tb.numer;
            mt_timebase /= tb.denom;
            mt_timestart = mach_absolute_time();
        }

        double diff = (mach_absolute_time() - mt_timestart) * mt_timebase;
        tp->tv_sec = diff * MT_NANO;
        tp->tv_nsec = diff - (tp->tv_sec * MT_GIGA);
    }
    else // other clk_ids are mapped to the coresponding mach clock_service
    {
        clock_serv_t cclock;
        mach_timespec_t mts;

        host_get_clock_service(mach_host_self(), clk_id, &cclock);
        retval = clock_get_time(cclock, &mts);
        mach_port_deallocate(mach_task_self(), cclock);

        tp->tv_sec = mts.tv_sec;
        tp->tv_nsec = mts.tv_nsec;
    }

    return retval;
}
```

Comment: Copied this into a gist for future reference: https://gist.github.com/alfwatt/3588c5aa1f7a1ef7a3bb

Comment: pre-dividing the mt_timebase might have an adverse effect on accuracy, though. Not on x86, where both numer and denom are 1, but on ARM.

Answer (score 4):

Just use **Mach Time**.
It is public API, it works on macOS, iOS, and tvOS and it works from within the sandbox.

Mach Time returns an abstract time unit that I usually call "*clock ticks*". The length of a clock tick is system specific and depends on the CPU. On current Intel systems a clock tick is in fact exactly one nanosecond but you cannot rely on that (may be different for ARM and it certainly was different for PowerPC CPUs). The system can also tell you the conversion factor to convert clock ticks to nanoseconds and nanoseconds to clock ticks (this factor is static, it won't ever change at runtime). When your system boots, the clock starts at `0` and then monotonically increases with every clock tick thereafter, so you can also use Mach Time to get the uptime of your system (and, of course, uptime is monotonic!).

Here's some code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <mach/mach_time.h>

int main ( ) {
    uint64_t clockTicksSinceSystemBoot = mach_absolute_time();
    printf("Clock ticks since system boot: %"PRIu64"\n",
        clockTicksSinceSystemBoot
    );

    static mach_timebase_info_data_t timebase;
    mach_timebase_info(&timebase);
    // Cast to double is required to make this a floating point devision,
    // otherwise it would be an interger division and only the result would
    // be converted to floating point!
    double clockTicksToNanosecons = (double)timebase.numer / timebase.denom;

    uint64_t systemUptimeNanoseconds = (uint64_t)(
        clockTicksToNanosecons * clockTicksSinceSystemBoot
    );
    uint64_t systemUptimeSeconds = systemUptimeNanoseconds / (1000 * 1000 * 1000);
    printf("System uptime: %"PRIu64" seconds\n", systemUptimeSeconds);
}
```

You can also put a thread to sleep until a certain Mach Time has been reached. Here's some code for that:

```
// Sleep for 750 ns
uint64_t machTimeNow = mach_absolute_time();
uint64_t clockTicksToSleep = (uint64_t)(750 / clockTicksToNanosecons);
uint64_t machTimeIn750ns = machTimeNow + clockTicksToSleep;
mach_wait_until(machTimeIn750ns);
```

As Mach Time has no relation to any wallclock time, you can play around with your system date and time setting as you like, that won't have any effect on Mach Time.

There's one special consideration, though, that may make Mach Time unsuitable for certain use cases: T**he CPU clock is not running while your system is asleep!** So if you make a thread wait for 5 minutes and after 1 minute the system goes to sleep and stays asleep for 30 minutes, the thread is still waiting another 4 minutes after the system has woken up as the 30 minutes sleep time don't count! The CPU clock was resting as well during that time. Yet in other cases this is exactly what you want to happen.

Mach Time is also a very precise way to measure time spent. Here's some code showing that task:

```
// Measure time
uint64_t machTimeBegin = mach_absolute_time();
sleep(1);
uint64_t machTimeEnd = mach_absolute_time();
uint64_t machTimePassed = machTimeEnd - machTimeBegin;
uint64_t timePassedNS = (uint64_t)(
    machTimePassed * clockTicksToNanosecons
);
printf("Thread slept for: %"PRIu64" ns\n", timePassedNS);
```

You will see that the thread doesn't sleep for exactly one second, that's because it takes some time to put a thread to sleep, to wake it back up again and even when awake, it won't get CPU time immediately if all cores are already busy running a thread at that moment.

### Update (2018-09-26)

Since macOS 10.12 (Sierra) there also exists `mach_continuous_time`. The only difference between `mach_continuous_time` and `mach_absolute_time` is that continues time also advances when the system is asleep. So in case this was a problem so far and a reason for not using Mach Time, 10.12 and up offer a solution to this problem. The usage is exactly the same as described above.

Also starting with macOS 10.9 (Mavericks), there is a `mach_approximate_time` and in 10.12 there's also a `mach_continuous_approximate_time`. These two are identical to `mach_absolute_time` and `mach_continuous_time` with the only difference, that they are faster yet less accurate. The standard functions require a call into the kernel as the kernel takes care of Mach Time. Such a call is somewhat expensive, especially on systems that already have a [Meltdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meltdown_(security_vulnerability)) fix. The approximate versions won't have to always call into the kernel. They use a clock in user space that is only synchronized with the kernel clock from time to time to prevent that it is running too far out of sync, yet a small deviation is always possible and thus it is only the "approximate" Mach Time.

Comment: `mach_approximate_time()` requires Mac 10.10+

Comment: @Vortico See https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-4570.1.46/osfmk/mach/mach_time.h.auto.html  - `__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_9, __IPHONE_8_0)`

Comment: Interesting, [this document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/1462443-mach_approximate_time) says 10.10, and I wasn't able to load a binary that links to that function in 10.9.

Comment: @Vortico I think it's only official API since 10.10 but if you use it in code and compile it for 10.9, it should actual work. You just couldn't do so on 10.9 systems as it was not present in the headers but if build on a newer system, it should deploy back to 10.9

Comment: That's different what I was experiencing. The symbol was not found when attempting to run a binary compiled on a later Mac version.