# What can I do to always have a CLOCK_MONOTONIC defined?

Tags: c, linux, performance, clock

Is there any portable way (for now on just for GNU/Linux) to always have a CLOCK_MONOTONIC defined? Or is there a similar way to have such clock which will be portable in Linux environments?  **I mean: is there any portable way to always have a MONOTONIC clock, not affected by settime()/settimeofday()?**

Now I use it with no problem, I have Ubuntu 12.4, use gcc and compile: gcc test.c -o test, thats all. But I need a portable way to always have a MONOTONIC clock in GNU/Linux. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GNU/Linux with sufficiently recent kernels (somewhere in the 2.6.x series), you can use CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, but other than that, portably all you have is CLOCK_MONOTONIC.

In case you are unaware, some POSIX systems don't even have clock_gettime, such as OS X (see [Monotonic clock on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680461/monotonic-clock-on-osx) for the OS X way).