# clock_gettime on MacOS

Tags: c, macos, time

`clock_gettime` doesn't work on MacOS Sierra anymore. Pretty sure I had this compiling correctly before Xcode 8 came out. I am really kind of stuck on what to do to get it to compile correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <time.h>

int main(){
    struct timespec time1, time2;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&time1);
    //Some code I am trying to work out performance of...
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&time2);
    printf("Time Taken: %ld",time2.tv_nsec - time1.tv_nsec);
}
```

Code like this simply fails to compile. I've been told the sierra timing library has changed. I get a compiler error for `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` not being defined and a warning for implicit declaration of `clock_gettime`, which turns into an error if I define `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` to something random, as it then just errors out during the linking stage.

Does anyone know of a fix or workaround to get the code compiling and executing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` has been around in recent times.

I believe what you want is probably `mach_absolute_time()` plus a conversion, as documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1398/_index.html); this appears to be monotonic, and absolute (which are two different things as you probably know).

Other useful hints are to be found at the following related (but I think not duplicate) questions:

- [clock_gettime alternative in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167269/clock-gettime-alternative-in-mac-os-x) (but deals with a different clock type)
- [Monotonic clock on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680461/monotonic-clock-on-osx) (not C but objective C)